# jest gives undefined for class in static property

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, vitest

I am trying to create some testcases in jest for [ecsy](https://ecsyjs.github.io/ecsy/docs/#/).

So I have created a bunch of systems, for example

```js
export class TargetSystem extends System {
    static queries = {
        calibrationPoints: {
            components: [CalibrationPoint]
        }
    }
}
```

that references a component in a different file(if that matters)

```js
export class CalibrationPoint extends Component {
    static schema = {
        position: { type: Types.Ref },
        index: { type: Types.Number }
    }
    position: Vec2;
    index: number;
}
```

This seems to work flawlessly in the browser and seems to be up to spec with what is written in the ecsy documentation.

However when creating the ecs system and registering the `TargetSystem` (after the components are registered) I get an undefined error, because for some reason that I can't quite figure out `TargetSystem.queries.calibrationPoints.components` is equal to `[undefined]`.

What is weird is that it seems to work in some cases (could be that all failing cases are refencing other files) and that if I manually, in my test write `TargetSystem.queries.calibrationPoints.components[0] = CalibrationPoint` then it works... but it is not a reasonable way to set things up.

So what could I be missing here?

also, here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  }
}
```

and my jest config

```
export default {
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.[tj]s$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.json' }],
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!three)"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js"]
}
```

---edit

seems like the idea of imports being the issue was wrong.
I tried creating a new component and referencing it in a system and it makes no difference if it was created in a different file or in the same one as the system

Could be interesting to note that I seem to get the same issue if I test it with vitest

--- edit2

Seems like I can boild it down even further.
ex

```js
//Calibration.ts
export class SolutionRef extends Component {
    static schema = {
        solution: { type: Types.Ref }
    }
    solution: Solution
}
//Target.ts
import { SolutionRef } from "./Calibration";

console.log("solution", SolutionRef)
```

and it logs

```
stdout | src\ECS\Target.ts:8:9
solution undefined
```